# Setting the value of a Unity script variable from an Android activity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am working on an Android application that uses Unity. I have a Unity script. In this script I have a variable whose value is set at runtime. This variable is the path of a obj model.
**What I want is to set the value of this variable from an android activity.**

I have found a link related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121781/calling-android-ndk-function-from-unity-script),
but in this the Java side is being used as a plugin in Unity. And I am doing the opposite (using Unity activity as a plugin in Android).

How can I set this variable in my Unity script using an Android activity?

Comment: What kind of activity?

Comment: from an Activity class

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a library called [Sphero](https://github.com/orbotix/UNITY-PLUGIN). Although I haven't used it yet, it might be of interest as it aims to ease communications between Unity3D and the native layer on both iOs and Android.