# Launch URL in Android Browser From Unity

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine

This is follow up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121781/calling-android-ndk-function-from-unity-script)

I am trying to open a url in browser in android device - 
so i modified the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121781/calling-android-ndk-function-from-unity-script) code -

```
 public void getURL(Object url) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url.toString()));
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Chose browser"));
  }
```

but unfortunately i am unable to open any browser dialog.
Logcat stats some - checkComponentPermission, but i am not doing any fancy in my project (this is just a test project).

any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to manifest

add this

```
 <manifest xlmns:android...>
 .....
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 ......
  </manifest>
```